# How to change prepended text when toggled in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, prepend

I have some content that I am show/hiding using the Jquery toggle function.

I have prepended an arrow to each heading and would like to change the prepended arrow to a downwards arrow when the content is toggled.

Code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show-hide-list h3 a').prepend('&gt;&nbsp;');//Prepend arrow
    $('.show-hide-list li .show-hide-list-content').hide();//Hide content
    $('.show-hide-list h3').click(function() {//Perform toggle when clicked
        $(this).next('.show-hide-list-content').toggle();
        //Need to change orientation of prepended arrow when toggled
        return false;
    });
});
```

The html is as follows:

```
<ul class="show-hide-list">
<li>
       <h3><a href="#">Heading</a></h3>
   <div class="show-hide-list-content">
           Content to be toggled here.
       </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

How can I change the arrow orientation once toggled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your arrow in a span tag so you can easily select it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show-hide-list h3 a').prepend('<span>&gt;&nbsp;</span>');//Prepend arrow
    $('.show-hide-list li .show-hide-list-content').hide();//Hide content
    $('.show-hide-list h3').click(function() {//Perform toggle when clicked
        $(this).next('.show-hide-list-content').toggle();
        var arrow = $(this).find('span');

        if (arrow.text().indexOf('V') >= 0) {
            arrow.html('&gt;&nbsp;');  
        } else {
            arrow.html('V&nbsp;');
        }
        //Need to change orientation of prepended arrow when toggled
        return false;
    });
}); ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6DB7t/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a class to that arrow, assuming your users' browsers would support it.  Start with some some CSS like this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
```

Or just toggle a downward arrow image's visibility, which would work on any modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the arrow in a `<span>` and give it a proper class, so you can find it again later: For example like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.show-hide-list h3 a').prepend('<span class="togglearrow">&gt;&nbsp;</span>');
//Prepend arrow
$('.show-hide-list li .show-hide-list-content').hide();//Hide content
$('.show-hide-list h3').click(function() {//Perform toggle when clicked
    $(this).next('.show-hide-list-content').toggle();

    $(this).parent().find('.togglearrow').html('V ');
    //V represents downward arrow

    //Need to change orientation of prepended arrow when toggled
    return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `prepend` I would recommend using the `:before` pseduo selector or a `background-image` to create the arrows.  This is a presentational thing so it really should be handled by CSS.

**Live, functional example** using the `:before` pseduo selector - http://jsfiddle.net/Nfw7y/

If you need more control over the look of the arrows I would recommend using a `background-image` or an [icon font](http://css-tricks.com/using-fonts-for-icons/).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have

```
$('.show-hide-list h3 a').html( $('.show-hide-list h3 a').html().replace('&gt;', 'V') );
```